# Are "Tresca yield surface" a type of failure mechanism?

Tags: structural-analysis, stresses, failure-analysis

A non-rigid solid was given a x-direction point load, and von Mises yield criterion is used to check whether the solid would fail or not.
[image]
I was also asked: "(the previous question asks us to modify the dimensions of the solid and check its von Mises stress) ensures that yielding will not occur in the optimized bracket under the given load. What other failure mechanism could potentially take place?" I plan to use "Tresca yield surface" as my "other failure mechanism". Is this criterion a type of failure mechanism?

Comment: [Yield surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_surface#Tresca_yield_surface) are yield criteria. "Surface" comes from representation of yield criteria in principal stress space.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? The context isn't clear. The part could fracture if there's some brittle character; the von Mises criterion is for ductile solids. The part could [creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creep_\(deformation\)), especially if heated. The part could buckle laterally. Fatigue (gradual crack propagation) could occur from repeated loading. And so on. These are all failure mechanisms.